# How do you bring buttons in front of a background image on an access form?

Tags: forms, ms-access

I'm building an access database for my music catalog. I've created one main table with a bunch of queries. I want to make a decent looking front end. I have a bunch of buttons with macros assigned to them already. The problem (which I presume is something very small that I'm missing) is that I added the background image after the buttons were already on the form.

The background image overlapped all of the buttons and in form view you can't see the buttons. Even in design view they're no longer visible. Is there a property in the property sheet that I'm missing ? I want the buttons to be overlapping or in front of the background image.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you and Happy Thanksgiving. a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the form in Design view.

On the ribbon on top, there should be these buttons

[image: Send To Back]

Select the image, and use them to send it to the background.